# How do I know the host computer turn on or turn off?

Tags: network

I am using a client computer that is connected to a modem via a LAN cable which is in a neighboring house as far as about 50 meters. The host computer is there. The host computer is only using Internet Connection Sharing (without a router) to share its Internet connection with me. Within this network there are only two computers, the one I use (as client) in my house and the other one is the host computer as I mentioned earlier.

How do I know that the host computer is being turned on or off?

The purpose is to know so that I can use all the bandwidth from the modem when the host computer is not turn on. Because there are no restrictions on bandwidth from the host computer, and I just wanted to use all the available bandwidth only when the host computer is not turned on.

Both computers use Windows 7.

Comment: This is more of a basic networking question than a security question. Using ping in the command prompt will tell you if it is on/connected. Use ipconfig on the other pc to find out what IP address to ping.

Comment: *`The host computer is only using Internet Connection Sharing`* You mean it's being used as a bridge or do you connect (Your long LAN cable) directly to the router?

Comment: To J.A.K: Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

Comment: To Azteca: We are not using a router, the LAN cable is directly connected to one port of the modem. I do not know if it a bridge or not, because i don't know about something called bridge :)

Comment: That ping was to the modem or to the *`host computer`*? The modem will almost always answer even if there's no internet.

Comment: To Azteca: Yes you are right it always give answer from that IP. The setting from IPv4 on both computer: Obtain an IP Address automatically. So how I can get know if the host PC are turned on or off?

Comment: @Stiev What you want is to know the IP of that other computer and ping him, just posted an answer with some details on it. TIP: Use the markup to deliver a notification like this `@userName`

Comment: @Azteca Ok thank you for your advice... this is my first run on stackexchange :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're connected directly to the Modem (Given that is provided by the ISP) in most countries it works as a router (**Layer 3**, 2 and 1 device) meaning that it redirects traffic and it's the gateway of your LAN to the WAN.

If you got a 192.168.1.1 IP this means *the modem* is [NATing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), so it's most likely you're both on the same network. Assuming that the firewall is on default settings, the *host computer* should be able to reply ICMP (ping / echo request), so just figure out his IP, either by actually asking your neighbor and pinging it, or doing a [ping sweep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_sweep) with tools like [Nmap](https://nmap.org/) or [Angry Ip Scanner](http://angryip.org/) and if it times-out, it's off, if it replies, it's on.

[READ THIS: PING SWEEP DISCLAIMER](https://nmap.org/book/legal-issues.html)

Comment: Just realized that this has nothing to do with security, should've been moved to superUser or serverfault stackExchange.